# What happens to hadoop job when the NameNode is down?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

In Hadoop 1.2.1, I would like to know some basic understanding on these  below questions

1. Who receives the hadoop job? Is it NameNode or JobTracker?
2. What will happen if somebody submits a Hadoop job when the NameNode is down?Does the hadoop job fail? or Does it get in to Hold?
3. What will happen if somebody submits a Hadoop job when the JobTracker is down? Does the hadoop job fail? or Does it get in to Hold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Client submits job to the Namenode. Namenode looks for the data requested by the client and gives the block information.

JobTracker is responsible for the job to be completed and the allocation of resources to the job.

In Case 2 & 3 - Jobs fails.

Answer (score 1):

By Hadoop job, you probably mean MapReduce job. If your NN is down, and you don't have spare one (in HA setup) your HDFS will not be working and every component dependent on this HDFS namespace will be either stuck or crashed.

1) JobTracker (Yarn ResourceManager with hadoop 2.x)

2) I am not completely sure, but probably job will become submitted and fail afterwards

3) You cannot submit job to a stopped JobTracker.